# Find all cosets of $H$ and $K$ in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ and $H = \langle(3, 2) \rangle$ and $K = \langle(4, 2)\rangle$. Find all cosets to H and K.

We have

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
G & = \mathbb{Z}_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4} \\
& = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, 9 \} \times \{0, 1, 2, 3 \} \\
& = \{(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), \ldots, (1, 3), (2, 0), \ldots, (2, 3), \ldots, (9, 0), \ldots, (9, 3) \} ,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
H & = \langle(3, 2)\rangle \\
& = \{k \cdot (3, 2) : k \in \mathbb{Z} \} \\
& = \{ (k \cdot 3, k \cdot 2) : k \in \mathbb{Z} \} \\
& = \{(0, 0), (3, 2), (6, 0), (9, 2), (2, 0), (5, 2), (8, 0), (1, 2), (4, 0), (7, 2) \} ,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

since

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
0 \cdot (3, 2) = (0, 0) \quad &\land \quad 1 \cdot (3, 2) = (3, 2) \quad \land \quad 2 \cdot (3, 2) = (6, 0) \\
3 \cdot (3, 2) = (9, 2) \quad & \land \quad 4 \cdot (3, 2) = (2, 0) \quad \land \quad 5 \cdot (3, 2) = (5, 2) \\
6 \cdot (3, 2) = (8, 0) \quad & \land \quad 7 \cdot (3, 2) = (1, 2) \quad \land \quad 8 \cdot (3, 2) = (4, 0) \\
9 \cdot (3, 2) = (7, 2) \quad & \land \quad \ldots 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}.

Now, in order to find all cosets of H, do I have to check for every $(a, b) \in G$ what sets I receive when I compute $(a, b) + H = \{(a, b) + h : h \in H \}$? I.e. do I have to compute 40 different sets? Is there a less brute force/tedious method?

Comment: No! you need not compute 40 sets separately .First note that $a+H=H$ iff $a \in H$, so take $(a,b) \in G \setminus H$ and use $a+H=b+H $ iff $a-b \in H$. For example, we do not compute both $(9,3)+H$ and $(0,1)+H$ because both are representing the same set

Comment: For future setting, use \$\langle\$ for the symbol $\langle$ instead of clicking $<$ in keyboard. Similarly  use \$\rangle\$ for the symbol $\rangle$

Comment: @ChinnapparajR I understand. I will use the correct formatting next time. What happens to the elements which give me negative values. I.e. $(0, 0) - (0 , 1) = (0 , -1)$?

Comment: which means $(0,0) \;\text{plus additive inverse of (0,1)}$ which is same as $(0,0)+(0,3)=(0,3)$ or note that $-1 \equiv 3 \;\text{mod 4}$

Comment: First understand the number of left or right cosets of $H$ in $G$ is $\frac{\vert G \vert}{\vert H \vert}$

Comment: @ChinnapparajR I know from Lagrange's Theorem that $|H|$ divides $|G|$ and I know from a Lemma from my lecture notes that the cardinality of a coset is equal to the cardinality of the subgroup. So then, in this case, there will be $\frac{40}{10} = 4$ cosets. However, checking all $a - b \in H$ seems tedious as well to go through each subtraction individually.

Comment: So as a follow up to my previous comment. Since there will be 4 cosets in total and we know that one of the cosets is $a + H = H$ for $a \in H$, we have 3 more to go. Now since, $(9, 3) - (9, 2) = (0, 1) \notin H$ we found two more cosets which leaves only one more. Hence, if I can find another one that does not represent the same set by subtracting and checking if it is in H, then I am done?

Comment: Yes ! it is one method but I don't know anything further about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me do it for $H$. You have found that $|H|=10$, so that there will be four cosets (by Lagrange).

One of them is $H$. You also know that distinct cosets are disjoint. Thus, pick an element not in $H$, say $(1,0)$; then a new coset is
$$
(1,0)+H=\{(1, 0), (4, 2), (7, 0), (0, 2), (3, 0), (6, 2), (9, 0), (2, 2), (5, 0), (8, 2) \}
$$
Is there an element not yet listed? Yes, $(0,1)$. Then a new coset is
$$
(0,1)+H=\{(0, 1), (3, 3), (6, 1), (9, 3), (2, 1), (5, 3), (8, 1), (1, 3), (4, 1), (7, 3) \}
$$
Now find an element not yet listed and do the same to find the fourth and last coset.

Comment: I think I found them myself: These are

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(9, 3) + H & = \{(9, 3) + h : h \in H\} \\
& = \{(9, 3), (12, 5), (15, 3), (18, 5), (11, 3), (14, 5), (17, 3), (10, 5), (13, 3), (16, 5) \} \\
& = \{(9, 3), (2, 1), (5, 3), (8, 1), (1, 3), (4, 1), (7, 3), (0, 1), (3, 3), (6, 1) \} ,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(9, 1) + H & = \{(9, 1) + h : h \in H\} \\
& = \{(9, 1), (12, 3), (15, 1), (18, 3), (11, 1), (14, 3), (17, 1), (10, 3), (13, 1), (16, 3) \} \\
& = \{(9, 1), (2, 3), (5, 1), (8, 3), (1, 1), (4, 3), (7, 1), (0, 3), (3, 1), (6, 3) \} ,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(8, 2) + H & = \{(8, 2) + h : h \in H\} \\
& = \{(8, 2), (11, 4), (14, 2), (17, 4), (10, 2), (13, 4), (16, 2), (9, 4), (12, 2), (15, 4) \} \\
& = \{(8, 2), (1, 0), (4, 2), (7, 0), (0, 2), (3, 0), (6, 2), (9, 0), (2, 2), (5, 0) \} ,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: K: \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(9, 3) + K & = \{(8, 2) + k : k \in K\} \\
& = \{(9, 3), (13, 5), (17, 3), (11, 5), (15, 3), (9, 5), (13, 3), (17, 5), (11, 3), (15, 5) \} \\
& = \{(9, 3), (3, 1), (7, 3), (1, 1), (5, 3), (9, 1), (3, 3), (7, 1), (1, 3), (5, 1) \} ,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(9, 2) + K & = \{(9, 2) + k : k \in K\} \\
& = \{(9, 2), (13, 4), (17, 2), (11, 4), (15, 2), (9, 4), (13, 2), (17, 4), (11, 2), (15, 4) \} \\
& = \{(9, 2), (3, 0), (7, 2), (1, 0), (5, 2), (9, 0), (3, 2), (7, 0), (1, 2), (5, 0) \} ,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
(2, 1) + K & = \{(2, 1) + k : k \in K\} \\
& = \{(2, 1), (6, 3), (10, 1), (4, 3), (8, 1), (2, 3), (6, 1), (10, 3), (4, 1), (8, 3) \} ,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thank you for showing me how you tackled the problem. I was all over the place!

Comment: @saladsalad You're welcome. It's *much* more boring with $K$.